# Most efficient way of searching within a B-Tree node

Tags: database, binary-search-tree, binary-search, b-tree

What is the most efficient way to search for a key within a B-Tree node? For example, if I have a node with 100 sorted keys and I'm looking for key `23`, what would be the fastest way of searching for that key within that node? What do most B-Tree implementations do?

Comment: Binary search...

Comment: @MartinHeralecký I was thinking of binary search but I wondered how it would compare to something like a hash table.

Comment: Hashing table is not a B-Tree.

Comment: Complexity of binary search (i.e. in a B-Tree): O(log(n)). Complexity of access in a hash table: O(1).

Comment: @MartinHeralecký I was thinking of having a hash table within each node. You would search the B-Tree normally but inside each node you would use a hash table to find the key you're looking for. This seems like it would be possible.